# React Native Example App does not run in Expo Snack

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm learning React Native and trying to add a component to an Expo Snack for testing. I can't even get the example app to work though.

Is it something different about how Snacks work vs. a desktop development environment? I've encountered that type of difference using JSFiddle, for example.

I straight copy-pasted the code from the [Github repo](https://github.com/himelbrand/react-native-numeric-input/tree/master/Example) into [snack.expo.io](https://snack.expo.io) and it gave me an error:

```
Device: (946:881) Unable to resolve module 'module://expo-font.js'
  Evaluating module://expo-font.js
  Evaluating module://react-native-numeric-input.js
  Evaluating module://App.js
  Loading module://App.js
```

I've gotten this error before, but I've never been able to figure out why. Is it an issue with the package, which was updated just 7 days ago, or something else? Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

It may be due to missing of node modules in your project compared to the Github project. As the Stack.expo browser won't give us full freedom to install custom modules, I suggest you to download VS Code and open the Github project in it, then do "npm install" from cmd and "react-native run-android/ios".